# Retrieving an array value by key

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following code creating an array and attempting to dump/die the first item

```
$huh = [15,30];
dd($huh[0]);
```

With PHP 8.1, and Laravel 9.2:

- If used in a controller will correctly output 15
- When I use it in a test method or a regular class, it will output the whole array (same if I use echo):

  ```
  ^ array:2 [
      0 => 15
      1 => 30]
  ```

With PHP 8.1, Laravel 8.83.2

- It will correctly output 15 anywhere

I feel like I am going crazy. I don't understand what is happening. Can anyone help?

Update: It seems to be contained to running tests. It works in the controller because I output to the browser. It doesn't work when I run the code via a test (PHPUnit). Still don't know why.

Update 2: So I had been importing:

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

But when I changed to

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

The tests were correctly outputting 15. Still don't know why. But maybe I just stay away from Tests\TestCase; (I have a feeling it may be from a previous version of Laravel and no longer in use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe the issue was because I was importing

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

And not:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

It seems Tests\TestCase was perhaps from an old version of laravel and not compatible with Laravel 9.2. Stills seem like odd behaviour.

Update: So Tests\TestCase is still in use in Laravel 9.2, but it is used for feature tests, not unit tests. Still not sure why importing it into a unit test would cause that behaviour.